# Implement comet with JSP

Tags: jsp, comet, long-polling

I developed a chat application using JSP,
But up to know I used periodical Ajax requests to check for new messages.

Problem present in it checking the database at unnecessary times also,So I want to implement it using COMET.

May any tell to me how to implement COMET with JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Use DWR (direct web remoting) reverse ajax - http://directwebremoting.org/dwr-demo/reverseajax/peopleTable.html